# Sending mutlpart/form-data with Ajax and FormData

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm trying to send a file to the server using Ajax and the formData object. However I keep getting a "input.files[0] is undefined" Wondering if you could point me where I'm going wrong.

//html

```
<!--uploading new media-->
    <div class="uploadBtns uploadClass">
        <input type="file" id="uploadBtn" class="uploadClass" name="usersUpload" />
        <input type="text" id="uploadFile" class="uploadClass" />
        <span id="uploadBtnText" class="uploadClass">Browse Media...</span>
        <div id="uploadSubmitBtn" class="uploadClass" name="usersUploadSubmit" value="Upload Media">
            <span id="submitBtnText" class="uploadClass">Upload Media</span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

then the javascript:

```
 //send pictures via ajax
$("#uploadSubmitBtn").click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData();
    var inputFile=$("#uploadBtn");
    //append the actual file that was selected
    formData.append('usersUpload', inputFile.files[0]);
    $.ajax({
        url : "upload",
        type : 'post',
        data : formData,
        async : true,
        processData: false,  // tell jQuery not to process the data
        contentType: 'multipart/form-data', // tell jQuery not to set contentType
        error : function(request){
          alert(request.responseText);
       },
        success : function(resp){
          alert("got back " + resp);
       }
    });
});//end of submitting media
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var formData = new FormData($("#formname")[0]);
```

I don't know what your form is called so replace formname with the name of your form, actually on second view you don't have a form so put a form around your inputs

Set these in your ajax request:

```
async: false,
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false
```

Answer (score 0):

You are already using jQuery. So better to use `jquery.form.js` by Malsup.
[Check this link for plugin and usage.](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/) Works with file uploads also.

Example :

```
$('#myForm').ajaxForm( { 
     beforeSubmit: function(){
     }, 
     success : function(){
     } 
});
```

Comment: the thing is he doesn't have a form, which is why it isn't working, he is creating formdata from scratch without having an html form, so $('#myForm') is undefined so this wouldn't work anyways, no point in adding extra plugins if all you need is to add a form tag with an id to make it work

Answer (score 0):

hmmm....i'm not sure why adding the form element didn't make it work and still gave me the same error. I modified it thus though and it works now.

```
<!--uploading new media-->
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadForm">
        <div class="uploadBtns uploadClass">
            <input type="file" id="uploadBtn" class="uploadClass" name="usersUpload" />
            <input type="text" id="uploadFile" class="uploadClass" />
                <span id="uploadBtnText" class="uploadClass">Browse Media...</span>
            <div id="uploadSubmitBtn" class="uploadClass" name="usersUploadSubmit" value="Upload Media">
                <span id="submitBtnText" class="uploadClass">Upload Media</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

works better for me because I will be doing some multifile upload as well.
Thanks again

```
  //capture and send file uploads via ajax
$("#uploadSubmitBtn").click(function(){
    var formData = new FormData($("#uploadForm")[0]);
    var usersFiles=$("#uploadBtn").get(0).files;
    //append the actual file that was selected
    formData.append('usersUpload', usersFiles);
```